# SIGABRT error in swift after a button is pressed - the segue doesn't execute

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a leaderboard for a word scrambler app so I am saving the data before segueing to the next view controller which will eventually be a leaderboard. My outlets are all connected and the segue identifier was written correctly so I don't see why the app crashes after done is pressed

the error line occurs here: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var finalScore = Int()
var playerName = String()
var allMyStoredData = UserDefaults.standard
class secondVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
    var playerScore = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scoreLabel.text = "Your score is: \(finalScore)"
        loadData()
    }

    @IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        saveData()
        //this part won't execute
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLeaderboard", sender: self)
    }

    func saveData () {
        playerName = nameTF.text!
        playerScore = finalScore
        allMyStoredData.set(playerName, forKey: "saveTheName")
        allMyStoredData.set(playerScore, forKey: "saveTheScore")
    }

    func loadData () {
        if let loadPlayerName:String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "saveTheName") as? String {
            playerName = loadPlayerName
        }

        if let loadTheScore:Int = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "saveTheName") as? Int {
            playerScore = loadTheScore
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing it through Interface Builder.

Comment: You need to include the complete error message (as text) in your question and you need to point out the exact line causing the crash.

Comment: Try adding self before. Like this : self.performSegue(withIdentifier: ”toLeaderboard”, sender: self)

Comment: @Putte I just tried and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: 1.) double check your connections. Rightclick on BOTH viewcontrollers, and remove if needed. —— 2.) check the identifier again. Make sure you spelled everything correct. 3.) try chaning the presentating. Ex, to modally

Comment: @Putte I got it, the problem was in the other view controller, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update: there was an outlet in the view controller the segue "toLeaderboard" goes to which wasn't connected or used so I deleted it and now the code is fine